# Using UIAlertView for a GetReady title

Tags: ios, iphone, uialertview

I am trying to use UIAlertView to pull up a get ready title then pull it off the screen to let the player know the game is starting. How do I do this using UIAlertView?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a Get ready pop-up a timer and a Game Over pop-up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418232/adding-a-get-ready-pop-up-a-timer-and-a-game-over-pop-up)

Comment: Don't repeat questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Methods...

```
UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Get Ready!" message:nil     delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];;

[alertView show];

[self performSelector:@selector(dismissReadyAlert:) withObject:alertView afterDelay:3.0];

-(void)dismissReadyAlert:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
   [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];

   alertView.title = @"Your game is started!";

   [alertView show];

   [self performSelector:@selector(dismissStartAlert:) withObject:alertView afterDelay:2.0];
}

-(void)dismissStartAlert:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a reference to the alert.  Then just call this method:

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare **UIAlertView** Object in **header** file.

```
UIAlertView *alertReady;
```

Then Display alertview whenever you like to display and call one method to dismiss alertview

```
    alertReady = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Get Ready" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertReady show];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(hideAlertView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


-(void)hideAlertView
{
    [alertReady dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```